# Tensorflow outof memory after a few iterations

Tags: tensorflow

I am running a deeplearning project on a large dataset with GPU. Each image is about 200*200*200 voxel.

During training prograss, I received waring and OutofMemory Error at different iterations, maybe sometimes my program will end at first iteration caused by Outof Memory error, but sometime it will end after being trained hundreds of iterations for the same reason.

So I am wondering if it could be trained and have already ran some iterations, why the Outof Memory error will still occur??? I was not run other programs in that GPU and the batchsize is also fixed. Could someone please help me to fix it or provide some ideas about how to deal with it?

Some details:
Tensorflow will always warning like this:

`I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/pool_allocator.cc:247] PoolAllocator: After 13278 get requests, put_count=13270 evicted_count=1000 eviction_rate=0.075358 and unsatisfied allocation rate=0.0834463
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/pool_allocator.cc:259] Raising pool_size_limit_ from 100 to 110`

and after hunders of iterations, pragram will be stopped by Memory error(part of the output):

`...
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:678] Chunk at 0x33288a7e00 of size 17408
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:678] Chunk at 0x33288ac200 of size 17408
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:678] Chunk at 0x33288b0600 of size 6912
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:678] Chunk at 0x33288b2100 of size 6912
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:678] Chunk at 0x33288b3c00 of size 6912
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:678] Chunk at 0x33288b5700 of size 6912
...
...
W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:275] Ran out of memory trying to allocate 648.00MiB.  See logs for memory state.`

Some operations I used:  tf.nn.conv3d/tf.nn.conv3d_transpose/tf.nn.batch_normalization

Comment: Its hard to tell without looking at the code. Can you provide the code?

Comment: It seems that you are creating tensorflow nodes inside the training loop.